# SQLite; "Cannot add a PRIMARY KEY column"-Exception

Tags: c#, sql

today I have started coping with databases. I've installed SQLite and SQLite-net. I am Programming a Windows 8.1 App using C#.

All I have is the following:

A Model:

```
public class Subject
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

And the OnLaunched-Event in App.Xaml.cs contains:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs e)
{
[...]
    // Get a reference to the SQLite database
    DBPath = Path.Combine(
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "Subjects.s3db");
    // Initialize the database if necessary
    using (var db = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(DBPath))
    {
        // Create the tables if they don't exist
        db.CreateTable<Subject>();
    }
[...]
}
```

When I launch this I get the following error after db.CreateTable(); is executed:

Cannot add a PRIMARY KEY column.

What is going wrong here? I really would appreciate your help.

Thank you very much.

Greetings, FunkyPeanut

Comment: Not sure, but aren't you trying to create a table that already exists?

Comment: Hey, thanks for your fast comment. Well I am not sure but I think the "CreateTable" expression only creates a table if it does not exist. Hmm.... Thanks though!

Comment: You'd better check that. Setup a test database without any tables and see that happen.

Comment: Hmm you seem to be right. When I change the name of the Database to Subject.s3db everything works fine even when I relaunch or completely restart the app! Thanks for that! Wow. But still that leaves an even bigger question - why is that? This seems pretty strange to me. Understanding this error would help me avoid it in the future. Thank you very much dude! :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you've changed the schema of the DB table by adding or removing a field from your `Subject` class. I.e. you've added the `Id` property after having already run the application to create the `Subject` table.

This is why it works with a new DB file. You'll either need to modify the schema (which in SQLite involves creating a new table, copy data from the existing table, deleting existing table and then renaming the new table), or simply delete your old DB file and create a new one.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue ... this is so stupid but it was because when I copied / pasted code from another table I forgot to change its name ......

Before

```
[Table("CopiedTable")]
```

After

```
[Table("MyNewTable")]
```

Comment: This was exactly my problem too. The error message "Cannot add a primary key column" is not at all accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Doing Build/Clean sorted the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in a Xamarin.Forms app on Android. This was caused by a not very obvious fact that the Model class can have fewer properties when it is build in the Release mode compared to the Debug mode. This is because of the linker. It removes the properties that are not directly referenced in the code but only in the Release version. The Debug version still contains all the properties. So when you run the Release version of the app and then its debug version, it crashes with this confusing error.

I have fixed it by adding `[Preserve(AllMembers = true)]` attribute to the class to make sure it is the same in both the Release and the Debug mode.